# The declared package \"com.concept\" does not match the expected package

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have gone through many similar question but I could not solve my problem. So you could please guide me step by step I would be very grateful.

This is the error that is bothering me:
[image: This is the error that is bothering me]

Comment: You seem to have created a directory `com.concept`, instead of `com/concept` (so directory `concept` in directory `com`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: that's definitely one issue, but the error message suggests that the default package was expected (`""`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I hadn't picked up on that part of the error message That would suggest this `com.concept` is taken as a source root, instead of `src`.

Comment: I think you should modify your folder name, it should not contain `.` symbol. Otherwise, in Java, **concept** will be considered as the next level file of **com**.

Comment: Thank you very much my program started running. I have another doubt that why in my program under problem section the following is showing:- Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed

Comment: Use this method in code to close **sc**. `sc.close();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please modify your folder name, it should not contain `.` symbol. Otherwise, in Java, **concept** will be considered as the next level folder of **com**.

Comment: But that's what's intended. The problem is that `concept` will *not* be 'considered as the next level folder of `com`.'